# How to install php-redis extension on mac os 10.13?

Tags: macos, redis, homebrew, pecl

For a few days I'm trying to install php-redis extension.

Try use brew and getting this...

```
$ brew install php71-redis
Error: No available formula with the name "php71-redis" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Trying to install with PECL and getting this...

```
    $ sudo pecl install redis
    downloading redis-4.1.0.tgz ...
    Starting to download redis-4.1.0.tgz (220,774 bytes)
    ..............................................done: 220,774 bytes
    25 source files, building
    running: phpize
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:         20160303
    Zend Module Api No:      20160303
    Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
   ************

   ************
    checking whether to enable igbinary serializer support... yes
    checking whether to enable lzf compression... yes
    checking use system liblzf... no
    checking for igbinary includes... configure: error: Cannot find igbinary.h
    ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/redis/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --enable-redis-igbinary=нуы --enable-redis-lzf=yes' failed
```

and finally trying to install igbinary.h ....

```
$ sudo pecl install igbinary
downloading igbinary-2.0.7.tgz ...
Starting to download igbinary-2.0.7.tgz (73,523 bytes)

   ************

   ************


Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/igbinary/igbinary.h'
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/igbinary
```

Comment: I think you are maybe falling foul of **System Integrity Protection** by trying to create `/usr/include/php/ext/igbinary`, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204899  Maybe you can somehow install just for yourself in your HOME directories instead of in system directories for all users? Sorry, I do not know `pecl` that well.

Answer (score 7):

I just did this on Mac OS 10.13 (I'm still using High Sierra).

With homebrew php7.2 and up, `pecl` is now installed by default alongside the php binaries.

To see this for yourself type `which pecl`.

**Steps to install**

1. Check your version of redis, then find a suitable version of the extension [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis).
2. If unfamiliar with pecl, type `pecl` to see the options.
3. Issue `pecl install redis 5.0.2`. (or your version). Enter no to each question asked if you're not sure.
4. If that succeeds check the new file it created at: `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/redis.so`
5. The install will have added `extension="redis.so"` to top of your php ini.
   Check that by opening the file `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini`.
   (assuming you're on 7.3 there)
6. `brew services restart php`.
7. `php -i | grep Redis`

```sh
Redis Support => enabled
Redis Version => 5.0.2
```

Did this in September 2019 and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For this, try to disable the csrutil on OSx (Mac):

1. Reboot your Mac
2. When the Mac starts, typo Command + R until you get into recovery mode
3. In the recovery mode, go to utilities and select terminal
4. in the terminal type `csrutil disable`
5. Reboot your mac and redo the redis install by pecl

Should work.

Comment: I think you mean `Mac` https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh rather than `MAC` https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Comment: Hi Mark, you're right, I edited my reply. But easy to guess it regarding the title of this queston